# javascript does not work after form load through ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

I am using field collection module for showing some fields with add more option using ajax built in functionality of field collections. in my field collection I have added some javascript on some of the fields. As soon as I click add more button form loads well with ajax but javascript does not work please help.

Comment: Please provide your code, so that we could know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I HAVE DONE IT SUCCESSFULLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using `Drupal.behaviors` to add your javascript. The JS will be "re-attached" after the AJAX event as compared to say `$(document).ready` that will only run once on page load.

More info https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

Answer (score 2):

Behavior handling has changed again in Drupal 7, with modules now required to explicitly define their attach handler, and optionally specify a detach handler.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.example', context).click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you but i have done this.. using this approach sorry for updating